# How to return a value of DataSet in nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, c#-3.0

I am using the following code

but getting an error for returning the value

```
public DataSet GetImageGroupId(int CaseId)
    {
        NHibernate.ISessionFactory sessionfactory = NHibernateHelper.GetSessionFactory();
        NHibernate.ISession session = sessionfactory.OpenSession();

        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        queryBuilder.Append(string.Format("SELECT Id,Name,ImageModalityId from ImageGroup where BaseCaseId='" + CaseId + "'"));

        IQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery(queryBuilder.ToString()).AddEntity(typeof(ImageGroup));

        return // how to return a dataset.

    }
```

Please help me..

Comment: This link is very useful to solve my problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995411/how-to-return-a-value-of-dataset-in-nhibernate/6995969#6995969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rocky,

I think you are missing the purpose of  Nhibernate, the idea for NHibernate is to map your database to your domain object, so a class like this

```
public class ImageGroup
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int ImageModalityId { get; set; }
    public virtual int BaseCaseId { get; set; }
}
```

You can then used mapping files in Nhibernate to do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="NHibernateTest" assembly="NHibernateTest">
  <class name="ImageGroup" table="ImageGroup" lazy="false">
    <id name="id">
      <column name="id"/>
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name">
      <column name="Name"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ImageModalityId">
      <column name="ImageModalityId"/>
    </property>
    <property name="BaseCaseId">
      <column name="BaseCaseId"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and call it in method like this

```
    public class Start
    {
         static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;

        public Start()
        {
            using (ISession session = OpenSession()) {

                {

                    ImageGroup imagegroup1 = session.Get<ImageGroup>(1);
                }

            }
    }
               static ISession OpenSession() {
            if (SessionFactory == null) //not threadsafe
                { //SessionFactories are expensive, create only once
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
                SessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
}
```

I reference this [link](http://www.fincher.org/tips/Languages/NHibernate.shtml)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I have done the same way, now i have change the DataSet to List and now its working fine with my new Logic

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate is designed to give you back strongly typed objects, not data sets / tables.  I'd suggest mapping the results to an object and letting nhibernate retrieve them for you if possible.  If you absolutely need a data set you can get at the underlying connection to get at it in normal ADO.net fashion.

Something like this should work against SQL Server (using SqlClient namespace):

```
        using (var conn = session.Connection as SqlConnection)
        {
            conn.Open();
            var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT Id,Name,ImageModalityId from ImageGroup where BaseCaseId='{0}'", caseId), conn);
            var dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(dataSet);

            return dataSet;
        }
```